# Is this a typo in this econometric exercise?

Tags: proof-explanation, statistical-inference, regression, linear-regression

I'm trying to solve an exercise in OLS estimator:

> [image]

I'm not sure if $\mathrm{E}(u | \boldsymbol{x}, q)=0$ is a typo. Moreover, $\mathrm{E}(u | \boldsymbol{x})=0$ is used in the solution. Should it be $\mathrm{E}(u | \boldsymbol{x})=0$ rather than $\mathrm{E}(u | \boldsymbol{x}, q)=0$?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a typo. It seems natural to require $E(u\mid \mathbf x , q) = 0$ for your error term, and this is actually a stronger condition than $E(u\mid \mathbf x) = 0$.

To see this, recall that by the [tower property of conditional expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties), we have that $$E(u\mid \mathbf x) = E(E(u\mid \mathbf x , q) \mid \mathbf x) = 0.$$

Comment: Nice answer, but wouldn't this make it a stronger condition seeing as it implies the latter?

Comment: Whoops, that's what I meant. :) Thanks for pointing this out! @J.G

Comment: No worries, really nice answer!